# Topologically contractible algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gaga

From [a post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7374/the-jouanolou-trick/7602#7602) to [The Jouanolou trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7374/the-jouanolou-trick/):

> Are all **topologically trivial** (contractible) **complex algebraic varieties** necessarily affine? Are there examples of those not birationally equivalent to an affine space?

The examples  that come to my mind are similar to a singular $\mathbb P^1$ without a point given by equation $x^2 = y^3$. This particular curve is clearly birationally equivalent to affine line.

Perhaps the "affine" part follows from a comparison between Zariski cohomology and complex cohomology?

Comment: Same comment as on that one, you mean affine SPACE in your question, not affine line.  $\mathbb{A}^2$ is definitely contractible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No.  Counterexamples were first constructed by Winkelmann, as quotients of $\mathbb A^5$ by algebraic actions of $\mathbb G_{\text{a}}$.  I learned this from Hanspeter Kraft's very nice article available here:

[Challenging problems on affine $n$-space](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=SB_1994-1995__37__295_0).

Recently Aravind Asok and Brent Doran have been studying these kinds of examples in the setting of $\mathbb A^1$-homotopy theory, on the arxiv as [On unipotent quotients and some A^1-contractible smooth schemes](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703137).

Comment: This is a very interesting example -- I wonder if it's also not birational to affine line?

Comment: The first link's paper is really nice!

Comment: The link to H. Kraft's paper is broken

Comment: @Qfwfq, I fixed the link to Kraft's paper (I presume that I have the right one, and there is also a citation to Winkelmann's paper there).

Answer (score 11):

About the rationality of contractible varieties: **Yes** for curves and surfaces and is an **open question** for higher dimensions.

Any such contractible variety $X$ has $\chi_\text{top}(X)=1$, obviously.

If $X$ is a curve then it must have only cusps as singularities, if any, by a simple $\chi_\text{top}$ calculation. Now let $Y$ be a projective model of $X$ such that it is smooth at the points in $Y-X$. Topologically, $Y$ is a real surface without boundary such that a few punctures make it contractible. The only real surface with this property is $S^2$, obviously. Hence $Y$ better be rational and so is $X$.

If $X$ is an algebraic surface then it was a conjecture of Van de Ven that such a surface must be rational (actually his conjecture is for any homologically trivial $X$). This was proved by Gurjar & Shastri in:

- *[On the rationality of complex homology 2-cells](https://dx.doi.org/10.2969/jmsj/04110037)*
- Here is the [the part II](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-41/issue-2/On-the-rationality-of-complex-homology-2-cells-II/10.2969/jmsj/04120175.full) of the above paper (MathSciNet review number MR0984747)