# Étale cohomology of linear groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, etale-cohomology, reference-request

This is in a sense a follow up question to the answer here [Analytic tools in algebraic geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34717/analytic-tools-in-algebraic-geometry/34743#34743)

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic and let $R$ be the result of applying the Witt vector procedure to $k$ (see e.g. http://eom.springer.de/W/w098100.htm) This is a complete local ring with residue field $k$ and fraction field of characteristic 0. Let $L$ be an algebraic closure of the fraction field.

Using the procedure explained in SGA 4 1/2, pp. 54-56 one can construct, given a smooth scheme over $R$, a comparison morphism $H^*(X_1,A)\to H^*(X_0,A)$ where $X_0$ and $X_1$ are the fibers of $X$ over $Spec(k)$, respectively, $Spec(L)$, and $A$ is a finite abelian group of order prime to $char(k)$. The construction is as follows: we have the maps $X_1\to X\gets X_0$; due to the smoothness of $X$, the map $H^{\ast}(X,A)\to H^{\ast}(X_1,A)$ is an isomorphism, which we invert and then take the restriction to $X_0$.

These comparison maps are in general not isomorphisms, but they are if we take $X=GL_n(R)$ or $SL_n(R)$. I think I know how to prove this, but I also think this should be standard material. So I'd like to ask if somebody knows a reference for that.

Comment: Dear algori: I presume in the final paragraph you really meant to refer to the $R$-schemes ${\rm{GL}}_n$ and ${\rm{SL}}_n$ (which are quite different beasts from the groups ${\rm{GL}}_n(R)$ and ${\rm{SL}}_n(R)$).  Anyway, to deal with a general (necessarily split) reductive group scheme (with connected fibers) over a strictly henselian dvr, probably a good place to look is the paper "A topological property of quasi-reductive group schemes" by Fakhruddin and Srinivas in volume 2, issue 2, of Algebra and Number Theory Journal (2008). Just cross out "quasi-" everywhere. :)

Comment: Dear BCnrd -- thanks. The paper you mention doesn't seem to be on the arxiv, so I guess I'll have to check it in the library tomorrow. Re $GL$ and $SL$ -- yes, I did mean schemes over $R$, but what is the standard notation for them?

Comment: There is a proof by Deligne in SGA 4 1/2 passing through G/B which is smooth and proper and then G is an iterated $G_a$- and $G_m$-torsor over G/B.

Comment: Thanks, Torsten! Did you mean p. 230, end of Applications to trigonometric sums? (Actually I was thinking of another Leray spectral sequence, namely that of the map that takes a matrix to its last column; this makes sense for GL and SL and at least some other reductive groups as well.)

Comment: @algori: The standard notation is either $(GL_n)_R$ or $GL_{n,R}$.

Comment: Torsten's suggestion is the one that works quite generally.  For instance, Borel exploits it in a nice way in his elegant paper "On affine algebraic homogeneous spaces" where he adapts his earlier topological methods (with Harish-Chandra) over $\mathbf{C}$ to the algebraic case via etale cohomology to show that if $G$ is connected reductive then for a smooth closed subgroup $H$ the coset space $G/H$ is affine if and only if $H^0$ is reductive. Richardson has some other proof (which Borel references), but the cohomological one is quite nice. 

Comment: Kevin, BCnrd -- thanks! Yes, that spectral sequence is more general: it exists for any reductive group; but on the other hand it always has  a second differential, while the other one does not (of course if one is interested in proving an isomorphism this doesn't matter).

Comment: @algori: Yes, that is the place in SGA 4 1/2. Your suggested proof should also work but seems more involved geometrically. What you seem to need is to find nice "compactifications" (here this means a $G_m$-bundle over something smooth and proper) of matrices of fixed corank which of course can be done but is longer to describe than the G/B approach.

Comment: Torsten -- are $G_m$ bundles really necessary? I was thinking of generalizing the classical bundle $U(n-1)\subset U(n)\to S^{2n-1}$. One could start by proving an isomorphism for $\mathbf{A}^n_R$ minus the origin. Then one can compute the cohomology of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ of the closed and the generic fibers separately; one finds by induction a system of canonical multiplicative generators (assuming $A$ a ring) in odd degrees such that all generators but the last one restrict to the canonical generators of $\mathrm{GL}_{n-1}$ and the last one is the pullback of a generator of (continued)

Comment: the "sphere" $\mathbf{A}^n$ minus the origin. The generators are defined modulo multiplication by units of $A$. Then one proves by induction using the functoriality (with respect to the mappings $\mathrm{GL}_{n-1}\to\mathrm{GL}_n$ and $\mathrm{GL}_n\to\mathbf{A}^n$ minus the origin; both these mappings are defined over $R$) that the comparison maps are isomorphisms. The case of $\mathrm{SL}_n$ is similar.

Comment: @algori: It seems that your approach should work. I was thinking of being less explicit (no working out explicit differentials which I guess is what you are doing).

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken, but the article can now be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Witt_vector.