# On presentations of algebraic stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Every algebraic stack $X$ admits a presentation as quotient stack $[U/R]$ of a groupoid in algebraic spaces
($U$ is an algebraic space of objects, $R$ is an algebraic space of arrows, and there are two morphisms, source and
target, from $R$ to $U$)(see [Tag 04TI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04TI))

In the paper *Finiteness of coherent cohomology for proper $\text{fppf}$ stacks*, J. Algebraic Geom. **12** (2003), 357-366, doi:[10.1090/S1056-3911-02-00321-1](https://doi.org/10.1090/S1056-3911-02-00321-1), by Faltings, proving the coherence of higher direct images of coherent sheaves by proper maps of algebraic stacks, the proof starts (Section 3, page 6) 
with the choice of a presentation $X=[U/R]$ and the remarks

1) "We may assume that $U$ is affine"

2) "Furthermore, there is an étale covering $Y\to R$ with $Y$ affine",

without any additional justification.

My question, which is probably a basic fact in the theory of algebraic stacks, is: how to justify 1) and 2)?

Even if $X$ is an ordinary scheme, this is not completely obvious because the "obvious presentation" of $X$ will not 
satisfy 1) if $X$ is not affine. For $X$ a quasiprojective scheme, it seems to me that it follows from the Jouanolou's trick
(see e.g. [The Jouanolou trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7374/the-jouanolou-trick) ), but it is unclear to me how to treat the general case.

Maybe in general, given a presentation $[U/R]$, it is enough to replace $U$ by a disjoint union of affine schemes covering $U$ so that 1) is satisfied,
but then 2) is still unclear.

Comment: None of the morphisms are proper / finite.  So you can just replace your original $U$ by an etale quasifinite cover by an affine scheme.

Comment: Although some quasi-compactness assumption is needed to make sure we can choose a cover by *finitely many* affines (so that their union is again affine). In Faltings's paper, this is guaranteed by the running Noetherian hypothesis.