# Jouanolou's trick in the non-projective case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a connected scheme $X$ proper over $\mathbb{C}$, does there exist a scheme $X'$ affine and of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$, and a Zariski locally trivial $\mathbb{C}$-morphism $X'\rightarrow X$ with fibers isomorphic to affine spaces? I believe that this is true if $X$ is either smooth or projective.

Comment: is this a question not about research mathematics within the scope defined by the community?

Comment: First, the conditions imply that $X$ is smooth. Second, your question seems premature since if you google Jouanolou's trick you quickly learn that it works for any qcqs scheme by work of Thomason.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Wikipedia seems to say "Let X be a quasicompact and quasiseparated scheme with an ample family of line bundles. Then an affine vector bundle torsor over X exists." Not every qcqs scheme.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I had a slightly wrong formulation, now corrected.

Comment: The new version of the question does not follow from Thomason and therefore seems suitable for MO. I wonder if the existence of $X'$ implies existence of an ample family of line bundles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Jouanolou trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7374/the-jouanolou-trick)

Comment: I do not think that any of the answers there precisely address this question.

Comment: A simple way to construct proper varieties $X$ without an ample family of bundles is to take two disjoint isomorphic curves of different degrees in some projective space $Y$ and then identify points on one curve with points on the other (using any isomorphism). It seems quite likely to me that such varieties give a counterexample, but I don't see any simple way of proving this.